# Find Symmetric pairs in python

Tags: python, list, iteration, tuples, python-2.x

I have the below code to find and print all symmetric pairs from given input.

```
'''
 Given a list of number pairs.
 If pair(i,j) exist, and pair(j,i) exist report all such pairs.
'''

def find_all_symmetric_pairs(inp_dic):

    for key in inp_dic:
        val = inp_dic[key]

        if inp_dic[val] == key:
            return key,val
    return -1,-1


inp_dic = {'1':'3','2':'6','3':'5','7':'4','5':'3','8':'7'}

print type(inp_dic)
key,value = find_all_symmetric_pairs(inp_dic)

print "key:"+str(key)
print "value:"+str(value)
```

Output:

```
 key:3
 value:5
```

But if I change the input to

```
inp_dic = {(1,3),(2,6),(3,5),(7,4),(5,3),(8,7)}
```

or

```
inp_dic = {{1,3},{2,6},{3,5},{7,4},{5,3},{8,7}}
```

I have difficulty iterating. How do I achieve the same?

Comment: Show your error. It pretty much tells you exactly what the problem is.

Comment: Your input after `or` is not valid Python. That's basically a set of sets, which is not possible (not hashable) and does not makes sense (duplicates filtered out).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems like a useful solution:

```
d = {'1':'3','2':'6','3':'5','7':'4','5':'3','8':'7'}
pairs = [(key, value) for key, value in d.items()]
answer = [(x, y) for (x, y) in pairs if (y, x) in pairs]
print(answer)
```

**Output**

```
[('3', '5'), ('5', '3')]
```

It may also be faster if we make `pairs` a `set` instead of a `list`:

```
d = {'1':'3','2':'6','3':'5','7':'4','5':'3','8':'7'}
pairs = {(key, value) for key, value in d.items()}
answer = [(x, y) for (x, y) in pairs if (y, x) in pairs]
print(answer)
```

**Output**

```
[('3', '5'), ('5', '3')]
```

Comment: Thanks! Very elegant solution

Comment: Might be a bit faster by making `pairs` a `set`, and more elegant (in my opinion) by using `[(x, y) for (x, y) in pairs if (y, x) in pairs]`

Comment: @tobias_k thanks for your tips - I've updated my answer to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 2):

with a generator https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators

```
def find_all_symmetric_pairs(inp_dic):

    for key in inp_dic:
        val = inp_dic[key]

        if inp_dic[val] == key:
            yield key,val
```

Comment: This did not fix the issue I still get , "TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'"

Comment: @KurinchiMalar You can't put sets in sets, because they are not hashable. You could use frozensets, but that would not work, either, because sets have no order, so {1,3} and {3,1} are the same, and since sets have no duplicates, the second one would be thrown out before you could run your method.

Answer (score 1):

Well, for one you're changing the type of `inp_dic` to a set of tuples or a set of sets - which apparently shouldn't even work, since sets are unhashable:

```
>>> input_set = {{1,3}, {3,3}}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

But you can iterate over the set of tuples like this:

```
input_set = {(1,3), (42,23)}
for a, b in input_set:
    print(a, b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function `find_all_symmetric_pairs` actually only finds one symmetric pair. You can either make it into a generator function that will really iterate over all the keys:

```
def find_all_symmetric_pairs(inp_dic):

    for key in inp_dic:
        val = inp_dic[key]

        if inp_dic[val] == key:
            yield key,val
    return -1,-1

for key, val in find_all_symmetric_pairs(inp_dic):
    print "key: " + str(key)
    print "value: " + str(val)
```

or you can do the generation manually by appending to a list:

```
def find_all_symmetric_pairs(inp_dic):
    keys = []
    vals = []
    for key in inp_dic:
        val = inp_dic[key]

        if inp_dic[val] == key:
            keys.append(key)
            vals.append(val)
    return keys, vals

for key, val in zip(*find_all_symmetric_pairs(inp_dic)):
    print "key: " + str(key)
    print "value: " + str(val)
```

Keep in mind that  `inp_dic = {(1,3),(2,6),(3,5),(7,4),(5,3),(8,7)}` creates a set of tuples, while `inp_dic = {{1,3},{2,6},{3,5},{7,4},{5,3},{8,7}}` attempts to create a set of sets, which is illegal because sets are mutable and therefore unhashable. The first case will require more complex iteration than just using a dictionary because you will have to search all of the tuples for a matching key or value. To get around this, you can easily convert to a dictionary using a dictionary comprehension:

```
inp_dic = {(1,3),(2,6),(3,5),(7,4),(5,3),(8,7)}
inp_dic = {x[0]: x[1] for x in inp_dic}
```

Comment: @KurinchiMalar, you know you can change the selected answer any time you find a better one. Just saying...

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue the following way. Hence answering my own question.

```
def find_all_symmetric_pairs(inp_dic):

    for key in inp_dic.iterkeys():
        val = inp_dic.get(key)

        if inp_dic.get(val) == key:
            yield key,val
    return 


inp_dic = [(1,3),(2,6),(3,5),(7,4),(5,3),(8,7)]

inp_dic = dict(inp_dic)

for key, val in find_all_symmetric_pairs(inp_dic):
print "key: " + str(key)
print "value: " + str(val)
```